# Animal Population in Python

Tags: python

```
def main():
 wolf = int(input("Enter wolf population (initial): "))
 rabbit = int(input("Enter rabbit population (initial): "))
 grass = float(input("Enter total grass area, initially fertile (in sq yards): "))
 wolf_growth = float(input("Enter wolf growth rate (in percentage): "))
 rabbit_growth = float(input("Enter rabbit annual growth rate (in percentage): "))
 area_growth = float(input("Enter grass area annual growth rate (in percentage): "))

 for year in range(0,21):
     wolf = wolf * (1 + wolf_growth / 100)

     print()
     print("Year  Wolf Population  Rabbit Population Available Grass Area")
     print("%-2d%6d%19d%22.2f" %(year, wolf, rabbit,grass))

main()
```

It is my code, and it works. But I would need help to figure out how to properly finish coding based on additional calculations.
"Wolf population grows annually at the specific growth rate
input by user. Apart from this, every 5 years wolf population decreases to half of previous
year population due to widespread epidemic diseases. Given initial wolf population,
calculate wolf population for each year (Hint: Use modulo operator for computing
population in disease spreading years). Every year, wolf population needs to be updated
based on its growth rate as follows. Further, once in every 5 years except year 1 (i.e., only in years 6,11,16), Wolf population
must be made half of previous year’s Wolf population"

I tried using nested for loop for this part but could not make it work.

Thank you so much in advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a nested loop - you only need to put `if` statements inside your loop:

```
for year in range(0,21):
     # wolf population grows annually. You already did this part.
     wolf = wolf * (1 + wolf_growth / 100)

     # every 5 years, except the first year
     if (year % 5 == 0) and (year != 0):
        # wolf population decreases to half of the previous year population
        wolf /= 2

     print()
     print("Year  Wolf Population  Rabbit Population Available Grass     
       Area")
     print("%-2d%6d%19d%22.2f" %(year, wolf, rabbit,grass))
```

You can see that the line `wolf /= 2` only activates when `year` is both divisible by `5` (that's what the `%`, or 'modulo', operator does - takes the remainder after division. If the remainder after dividing `year` by `5` is `0`, then `year` is divisible by `5`) and is not equal to `0` (so, not the first year). Not sure if this handles your requirements exactly - what you posted in your question was slightly confusing - but this should be simple to adapt to your use case.

Comment: I appreciate your help, Thank you1

Comment: It does help, Sorry for confusing